# Multiple DB tables for one property in model

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following classes:

```
public class Customer {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string Surname {get; set;}
    public virtual string Prename {get; set;}
    public virtual Location Location {get; set;}
}

public class Location {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string ZipCode {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class CustomLocation : Location {
}
```

And the following mapping:

```
public class CustomerMapping : ClassMapping<Customer> {
    public CustomerMapping(){
        Table("Customer");
        Property(a => a.Surname, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
        Property(a => a.Prename, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
        ManyToOne(a => a.Location, b =>
        {
            b.Column($"FK_Location_Id");
        });
}}

public class LocationMapping : ClassMapping<Location> {
    public LocationMapping(){
        Table("Location");
        Property(a => a.ZipCode, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
        Property(a => a.Name, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
}}

public class CustomLocationMapping : ClassMapping<CustomLocation>{
    public CustomLocationMapping(){
        Table("CustomLocation");
        Property(a => a.ZipCode, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
        Property(a => a.Name, b =>
        {
            b.NotNullable(true);
        });
}}
```

My target is that I have a `Location` table that is being updated automatically by a script and a `CustomLocation` table where the user can add locations if there are some missing (or outside the country).

My problem is, that I don't know how to properly map this to the `Customer` that it can be both `Location` or `CustomLocation`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map one property to two columns in two different tables. How would NHibernate know, which table to use? You would also lose the referential integrity for that column.

However, your goal can be achieved by using a slightly different approach: Instead of using two tables for the same structure, just use one `Location`-table with the following class representation:

```
public class Location 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual bool IsSystem { get; set; } // just use a boolean column in the table for this one
}
```

Your script can insert / update / delete all the rows where `IsSystem == true` and ignore the rest. When the user adds an entry, just set `IsSystem = false`.

Comment: Yes I was aware of this problem with NHibernate, but I didn't know how to implement it differently. Many thanks for your answer! Should work like this.