# Two tables with the same structure and schema but different names requiring inserts and updates to one table - NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have two different tables with the same structure and schema in one database.

```
Comp.Employee
Comp.EmployeeTemp
```

Entity class:

```
public class Employee 
{
   public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

NHibernate fluent mapping:

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee> 
{
   public EmployeeMap()
   {
      Map(x => Name);
   }
} 

public class EmployeeTempMap : ClassMap<Employee> 
{
   public EmployeeTempMap()
   {
      Map(x => Name);
   }
} 

var manager = new Employee { Name = "Tom"}
Session().SaveOrUpdate("EmployeeTemp", manager)
```

I want to save the `manager` entity to `Comp.EmpoyeeTemp` table and not to `Comp.Employee`. I need to be able write to both tables but not at the same time using the same `Employee` entity. 
How can I do this in NHibernate and fluent mapping?

**Update:**
Updated my question to include the `EmployeeTempMap` mapping and the overloaded call to SaveOrUpdate()

Comment: Could you tell us the reason why it has to be the same `Employee` class for both tables? Could you have a base class with all the properties and two derived classes `Employee` and `EmployeeTemp` instead? The respective mapping files could derive from a common base mapping class and be different only for the `Table`-property. In order to load an employee from one table and copy it to the other table you would only need to write a simple cloning-method.

Comment: I didn't want to translate between the Employee entity and EmployeeTemp entity.  That's why I thought I just wanted to work with the Employee entity.  I didn't know you can use inheritance for the mapping.  I will try your suggestions.  Is there anyway I can tell the Save() method which mapping to use with the Employee entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rarely known/used NHibernate feature called "entity-name", which might enable you to do what you are trying to do - at least to some degree.

---

**Background information:**

An introduction to the feature can be found here: [Mapping the same class to a view and a table using entity-name](https://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/mapping/mapping-the-same-class-to-a-view-and-a-table-using-entity-name) (also applies to two tables with the same structure).

Fluent NHibernate also supports this feature, as can be seen in the source:
[fluent-nhibernate ClassMap](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/ClassMap.cs)

Relevant code from the above link:

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies an entity-name.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>See http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/21/entity-name-in-action-a-strongly-typed-entity.aspx</remarks>
public void EntityName(string entityName)
{
    attributes.Set("EntityName", Layer.UserSupplied, entityName);
}
```

---

**Disclaimer:** (the following code is untested but should put you on the right track. Feel free to edit when something is wrong or missing)

As mentioned in my comment to your question above, you can use inheritance for the class mappings like this (shortened example):

```
// Base class
public class BaseEmployeeMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Employee
{
    public BaseEmployeeMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.Name);
        // add all Properties that are common to both Employee and EmployeeTemp
    }
} 

// Mapping for Employee
public class EmployeeMap : BaseEmployeeMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap() : base()
    {
        EntityName("Employee");
    }
} 

// Mapping for EmployeeTemp
public class EmployeeTempMap : BaseEmployeeMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeTempMap() : base()
    {
        EntityName("EmployeeTemp");
    }
}
```

Now you can query and insert items by using the overloaded methods and supplying the `EntityName`:

```
// both tempEmployee and employee will be instances of class "Employee"
var tempEmployee = session.Get("EmployeeTemp", id);
var employee = session.Get("Employee", id);

session.SaveOrUpdate("EmployeeTemp", tempEmployee);
session.SaveOrUpdate("Employee", employee);
```

However, I have not verified that your goal (not having to "convert" an Employee to EmployeeTemp) can be achieved with this, because NHibernate might throw an error when loading the object with EntityName `EmployeeTemp` and trying to save it with the EntityName `Employee`. You might need to manually `Evict()` it from the session and then `Save()` it with the desired EntityName. (You might also need to clear the ID of the object.)

**Suggestion to make things simpler:**

I don't know the background of the design for two different tables with the same structure, but if your database structure is not set in stone, you could simply use one table `employee` and add a column `temp` and use that as a filter for your queries. When changing an `EmployeeTemp` to an `Employee` you would only have to flip the switch from `temp = 1` to `temp = 0`.

For a similar case look here on SO: [Multiple DB tables for one property in model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54802769/634872)

Comment: With the inheritance like the one above, can I do `session.SaveOrUpdate("EmployeeTemp", employee);`?  Basically when the request comes in, the service will check the Employee table. If new record, insert it into `EmployeeTemp` table. Otherwise, merge the incoming with the existing record and insert it into `EmployeeTemp`. Another process will transfer data from EmployeeTemp to Employee later after analysis.  I thought I can just copy the `EmployeeMap` to `EmployeeTempMap` and use the same `Employee` entity without needing to translate `Employee` to `EmployeeTemp` for `EmployeeTempMap`.

Comment: @hexterminator `session.SaveOrUpdate()` checks for the identifier of an object, so generally speaking, yes, it should work. Keep in mind that on order to use that overload of the `SaveOrUpdate()`-method you need to specifiy the `EntityName` in the Mapping.

Comment: @"Florian Lim" Thanks for answering my question.  I updated my original post to reflect what I was originally thinking.  I'm going to work on your suggestion using inheritance today and will followup.